# Charts in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, graph, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I want to create a graph similar to the picture I have attached or may be a bar graph. I am using Angular 4 and I have no idea about graphs in Angular. Is a reference link or some sample code available?

[![Graph][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve your requirement by using **Syncfusion angular-charts**. For more details about **Syncfusion angular-charts** please find attached demo and FT links.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zo5arc?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Screenshot:
[image: Syncfusion ng-charts]

FT: https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-charts

Demo link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/chart/spline

UG: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/chart/getting-started

Comment: You should probably point out that syncfusion is a "for pay" product and quite expensive. I would recommend some of the free options posted in the other answers.

Answer (score 43):

My Suggestions would be:

1. [Ng-Charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)
2. [D3.JS](https://d3js.org)
3. [PrimeNG has a charts section](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart)
4. [Dagre.js for DAGs (unfortunately in javascript)](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre)
5. [Ngx-graph for nice DAGs but no documentation and weak support](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph)
6. [ngx-charts from swimlane](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/force-directed-graph)
7. [HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs)
8. [Cytoscape.js for Directed Graphs](https://js.cytoscape.org/)
9. [mermaidjs](https://mermaidjs.github.io/)
10. [Canvas.js](https://canvasjs.com/angular-charts/) - Angular-focused charts instead of `HTML`.

Comment: my way would be create a REST API to get information from MongoDB in JSON and then use this JSON in Angular to show data on the frontend. I think it is possible. Start looking for REST API in MongoDB queries

Comment: thanks. Do you know the name of the map I have attached?

Comment: ng-charts seems to have only some of the charts available ...can u suggest anything else which acts as a wrapper on d3.js and we can draw almost all type of charts...

Comment: >almost all charts
I would strongly suggest sticking with `d3.js` for that matter. I have been on the lookout for such a library but haven't had any breakthrough.

Comment: @amrit https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/ is a ng2 wrapper for d3.js

Comment: I'm a huge primeng fan so glad they added charts, hopefully they expand them!

Comment: @MrChow you should go ahead an update the answer if you want with the prime face charts with the link

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/). This is not an Angular Module but can be used inside your angular App. Thats what I use.

There is also [eCharts](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts) I once used and it is very powerfull and has a good UI