# Angular 5 Data visualization - Dash-boarding framework

Tags: angular, angular5

Does anyone know angular project with data visualization capability?

We have looked into kibana and grafana based approached these frameworks are used into angular project using iframe, which we want to avoid due to security concerns.

We already have a charting solution using ng2 charts but is not flexible enough like dishoarded data visualization projects like kiban and grafana.

Any pointer or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Similar to [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811098/charts-in-angular-2/47811148#47811148)

Comment: Nope not similar, we are talking about implementation that allows user to visualise he can create his own chart, dashboarding and widget. Please visit kibana or grafana

Answer (score 0):

I have built such application with angular. Basically we started with existing tools such as **[`kibana`](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/integrate-kibana-into-angular-2-application/86402)** which provides high support for embed with Angular application.

When it comes to building a tool of your own, you could consider **[`ng2-charts`](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)** /[`highcharts`](https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts)/**[`primeng`](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart)**  charts those three ranks among the top when it comes to
charting library.

Integration will be more smooth when it comes to ng2-charts.

Comment: It is very difficult to construct queries like splunk... For multidimensional charts... Like grouped chart, bubble and all ng2 chart

Comment: That's what I have mentioned , mark if the answer helped

Comment: I am not looking for a charting solution, I do know about the charting solution you mentioned already but I am looking for a dashboarding solution where I can transform a SQL query to multi-dimensional chart. And provides UI with the flexibility to do the same. I know we have to create a wrapper above the charting framework. I want the full packages like kiban and grafana